# Klein's Protocols: A window into our mathematical past

Tags: ho.history-overview

**[Klein's Protocols](http://www.uni-math.gwdg.de/aufzeichnungen/klein-scans/)** in over 8,000 pages recording seminars organized from 1872 to 1913 by Felix Klein and given by Klein, his colleagues, students and other invited speakers, including luminaries such as Hilbert and Minkowski, provide a unique window into our mathematical past. Eugene Chislenko and Yuri Tschinkel have presented [a beautiful introduction](http://www.ams.org/notices/200708/index.html) to the corpus, noting how the breadth of the topics reflect the broad interests and knowledge of Klein (the authors claim that Klein was one of the last three grand mathemagicians able to soar over the full realm of the mathematics of their times, the other two being Hilbert and Poincare).

**Klein 's Protocols is huge and handwritten in German, so I thought it would be helpful for aspiring and established mathematicians with an interest in the history of ideas if a listing were available on Math Overflow of some gems in the corpus. Can you make a contribution?**

Please provide keywords and page references for any entry. E.g., personally, I would love to have a copy of the figure titled "On regular solids in 4-dimensional space" by W. I. Stringham in Vol. II on pg. 59 (Monday, November 29, 1880).

See also [these articles](http://www.claymath.org/library/annual_report/ar2006/06report_complete.pdf) (pages 16-21).

Comment: There is a similar list on Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Felix_Klein_Protocols). It would be good to combine the two lists.

Comment: This is handwritten in Sütterlin. I believe zou'll probably have a hard time finding anyone below the age of 60 who can fluently read Sütterlin.

I don't get it though:
Your aim is just a concise list of topic covered, or full translations?

Comment: @Malte: I just gave it a try. It's not easy to read, I agree (both the handwriting - not Sütterlin which was commissioned by the Prussian ministry for culture in 1911, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%BCtterlin - and the wording), but not much worse than reading modern handwriting... The major slowdown for me is the content, but there is no way to get around that.

Comment: The last pages of the examples I opened contain a table of content in the end. Has no one ever gotten these typed up and made publicly available? If not and others do the same, I would spend an hour or two to add some of these tables to the wiki page in order to get at least the content of all these seminars available.

Comment: @Malte : My goal was not so ambitious as to have a comprehensive listing of topics or translations, but questions often have a life of their own and this is a comm. wiki. I envisioned people occasionally perusing the Protocols, perhaps directed loosely by the Wiki article and the other references, and finding a page or two or equation or diagram that intrigued them that they could note here for others to enjoy and vote on according to their interests. Christian's offer sounds quite generous and a good way for people to narrow down their browsing or to initiate a more thorough study.       

Comment: @Malte: I am below the age of 60 and can read the handwriting. It is really not so hard to learn it.

Answer (score 18):

I compiled an index of the Protokolle which can be found here:

**http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/moritz/klein/**

I transcribed all the titels, names, dates and page numbers. You can do a case insensitive search. You can also view the scanned version there.

I hope this makes it easier to find the "gems in the corpus".

Comment: Great piece of work, thanks a lot for sharing!

Comment: Ditto to Stefan's.

Answer (score 5):

As said in the comments above, this is not right what Tom wanted, but I added the content of Volume 2 to the wiki, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Felix_Klein_Protocols. So far, I left it in German - do you think it is worth translating?

Comment: Nice! If the list is lengthened, it would be convenient to be able to do a page search in English for those of us who are not fluent in German. Thanks for the additional bio and other links in your list.